# TypeError when using sorting technique

Tags: python

I am getting a TypeError when I try to use recursion in my merge sort function. I am trying to return a tuple containing a list and a number. If only the list is returned, then my function is able to sort properly and return a sorted list, however.

My desired output:

```
([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...],100)
```

My merge function takes a list and simple lambda expression to compare two numbers.

```
def merge_s(list_s, ordering):

    if len(list_s) < 2:
        return list_s, 100
    result = []
    mid = int(len(list_s) / 2)
    y = merge_s(list_s[:mid], ordering)
    z = merge_s(list_s[mid:], ordering)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    first_item = ''
    second_item = ''

    while i < len(y) and j < len(z):
        first_item = y[i]
        second_item = z[j]
        if ordering(second_item, first_item):
            result.append(z[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            result.append(y[i])
            i += 1
    result += y[i:]
    result += z[j:]
    return result, 100
```

My main function:

```
from random import shuffle
def main():

    for i in range(10):
        data = list(range(100))
        shuffle(data)
        comp = lambda a, b: a < b #my compare function
        (sorted_data, _) = merge_s(data, comp)
        test = (sorted_data,_)
    print(test)
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge_s` returns: `result, 100`

However when you get the results of the recursive calls:

```
y = merge_s(list_s[:mid], ordering)
z = merge_s(list_s[mid:], ordering)
```

You treat it as if `merge_s` just returned `result` instead of a tuple of `(result, 100)`

```
while i < len(y) and j < len(z):
    first_item = y[i]
    second_item = z[j]
    if ordering(second_item, first_item):
```

This has a very simple fix where you just extract the result for `y` and `z`:

```
y, _ = merge_s(list_s[:mid], ordering)
z, _ = merge_s(list_s[mid:], ordering)
```

And with that fix your output is:

```
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99], 100)
```